# The usage of "muscle" in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, verbs

The usage of the verb **muscle** in this sentence from an [online article](http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/arts/la-ca-cm-chiaroscuro-woodcut-renaissance-20180705-story.html) sounds strange to me. According the several dictionaries I have consulted, **muscle** as a verb means *to force your way into a place or situation*, whereas in this sentence it apparently means *to be equipped with muscle*. I can only understand it as a similar usage to **four-legged**. Is my understanding correct? Is it a common usage at all?

> Diogenes, the contrarian beggar-philosopher, is seated before the big storage barrel that he lived in. The figure, wrapped in a swirl of billowing cloak, is powerfully **muscled**.

Comment: "Powerfully muscled" is an adjective phrase here, serving as subjective predicative complement of "be", with "the figure" as predicand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare:

> A horse is hoofed.
>
> Goats are horned.
>
> The stool was three-legged.
>
> He is said to be rather thin-skinned.
>
> The vaulted ceiling was ribbed.
>
> The saw was snaggle-toothed.
>
> Cerberus is three-headed.
>
> Most spiders are eight-eyed.
>
> The sloth is three-toed.
>
> Lady Macbeth was hard-hearted.
>
> Some dogs are long-haired.
>
> Cowards are said to be lily-livered and yellow-bellied.

The predicate using the past participle adjectivally in this way is often paraphrased as "equipped with {said feature}".